# tokenize a string in key value pairs in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, tokenize, key-value

we have to parse some strings with tsql

this are the strings I want to tokenize into key value pair tokens

```
<parameters>SearchName="Flat " SearchFormTemplateId="Search" SearchFormInfo=":ID_.Modules.Business.SearchModule.Label.SearchType.RE.Residential:LDSBL_15 km%15,10 km%10,5 km%5,20 km%20:LSTG_3,2,4:DR_3572ad9b-44cb-4229-a512-3037562d7cc7" SubTypeGroupId="3,2,4" InterfaceLocation="3.5908783699254903"§ CountryId="446931c9-7efe-440d-b674-24b8659087a7" Month="2000" AdMaterialTransactionTypeId="RE"/><azmi/></parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Apartment and.. " CountryID="446931C9-7EFE-440D-B674-24B8659087A7" DefaultRegionID="446931C9-7EFE-440D-B674-24B8659087A7" CurrencyID="USD" LocationID="5A7FCB90-6247-44FD-AB2E-61FEABEA1246,AFAC41AE-0877-45E1-BAA6-1846E9D92332,CCB35927-94CE-4F41-B4BA-695A0396DC5A,B93B2C1F-460A-4726-8B51-FFBEFC15C810,4E701DB8-6B3B-4C0E-91FB-352BEF05FB40,9FA7B3DA-9D36-4742-8526-5143F01E6089,384AF508-D5DC-4ED1-93D2-635180447A8D,49B571CC-FC2E-40F0-A5A7-722D6D1F5926,B0CA4856-427B-4C93-A085-95FA36C082B8,3590075E-9A63-4AF5-BE88-9C8BB70BACB7,E1283086-8C38-4A97-B858-ABE5940F2986,78060DDC-3F00-4AF0-AD17-AC0007FE0622,FE815C24-94D5-4107-989D-B0F5FB5280E8,356F506E-09C1-4E1E-B54E-C54E80E502DF,F028F134-4C13-491B-846C-D85B4D979A5F,7E4013DB-2DE3-401B-9AFF-F41C16B12DB4,5C59BC43-63B7-45D5-8963-F916A71ED889,DA8D9F2D-1C43-443A-86C7-F9661FF06830" TransactionTypeID="RE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="1,2,3,4" MMAX="2100" MoMin="1500" NumberOfRoomsMin="3" InterfaceLocation="1"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Apartment" DefaultRegionID="446931c9-7efe-440d-b674-24b8659087a7" CurrencyID="USD" TransactionTypeID="SE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="4" MMIN="100000" SearchBy="ByLocality" InterfaceLocation="1" LocationID="09194e31-1b5e-482b-9775-41886a1d1167" /><Keyid="6f4037e2-69ba-402d-a8ac-286b04e2bf3b"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Location, 3 rooms" CurrencyID="USD" LocationID="f5812b35-e952-4e3e-a3f1-b0d678616826" TransactionTypeID="RE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="2,3" MMAX="2500" NumberOfRoomsMin="3" SurfaceLivibleMin="80" SearchBy="WithoutGeo" InterfaceLocation="2" /><Keyid="079bb71a-8f01-42fd-a956-0be2239be0ef"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Flat..." DefaultRegionID="446931c9-7efe-440d-b674-24b8659087a7" CurrencyID="USD" TransactionTypeID="RE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="1,2,3" MMAX="4050" MoMin="2700" NumberOfRoomsMin="4.0" SearchBy="ByLocality" InterfaceLocation="1" LocationID="e22c7349-fd77-407a-88a4-bd39a105b986" /><Keyid="44e05bf1-8a26-48b6-b12b-5a652d586d78"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Apartment -" DefaultRegionID="446931c9-7efe-440d-b674-24b8659087a7" CurrencyID="USD" TransactionTypeID="RE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="4" MoMin="500" SearchBy="ByLocality" InterfaceLocation="1" LocationID="e7148138-5be1-46c5-98b1-5ca2edeeb9da" /><Keyid="37ad0ed5-1800-417b-8e17-9ff5084086a2"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Rent dsfsd" CurrencyID="USD" TransactionTypeID="RE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="4" SearchBy="WithoutGeo" /><Keyid="d695f924-6ce6-405b-a561-fa3269f41221"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Apartement ..." DefaultRegionID="446931c9-7efe-440d-b674-24b8659087a7" CurrencyID="USD" AreaID="e90f1e83-ce84-46b6-826a-3775ffd2815d,dc2c2435-b773-424f-a279-4141efd21b78,ce142f26-2b08-419d-86a2-943bea72b279,b5749fe2-9360-48c0-8ffc-f6c9a343f2fa,a3a559c2-4c7e-4b4c-8314-335e9e655472,c3cd7728-3e6a-4787-959f-8e9e824b02d0" TransactionTypeID="RE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="3,2,4" MMAX="1500" LocationIdAgregate="" AreaIdAgregate="e90f1e83-ce84-46b6-826a-3775ffd2815d,dc2c2435-b773-424f-a279-4141efd21b78,ce142f26-2b08-419d-86a2-943bea72b279,b5749fe2-9360-48c0-8ffc-f6c9a343f2fa,a3a559c2-4c7e-4b4c-8314-335e9e655472,c3cd7728-3e6a-4787-959f-8e9e824b02d0" StateIdAgregate="1D6E6621-3179-4D54-A9D8-89E6F438FF3B,8C79C6B5-B61A-45F9-8560-91AE4825AC6A" InterfaceAreaIdAgregate="e90f1e83-ce84-46b6-826a-3775ffd2815d,dc2c2435-b773-424f-a279-4141efd21b78,ce142f26-2b08-419d-86a2-943bea72b279,b5749fe2-9360-48c0-8ffc-f6c9a343f2fa,a3a559c2-4c7e-4b4c-8314-335e9e655472,c3cd7728-3e6a-4787-959f-8e9e824b02d0" SearchBy="ByRegion" /><Keyid="37ad0ed5-1800-417b-8e17-9ff5084086a2"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Apartment a" DefaultRegionID="446931c9-7efe-440d-b674-24b8659087a7" CurrencyID="USD" AreaID="49401e55-95c1-42cb-9242-9468707e7d8a" TransactionTypeID="SE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="16" AreaIdAgregate="49401e55-95c1-42cb-9242-9468707e7d8a" StateIdAgregate="97F9F29F-149E-4E53-A470-96CC8499A64B" SearchBy="ByRegion" /><Keyid="39fb945c-b048-4942-be86-17f692539ba3"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Apartment, Location, 5 rooms" CountryID="446931C9-7EFE-440D-B674-24B8659087A7" DefaultRegionID="446931C9-7EFE-440D-B674-24B8659087A7" CurrencyID="USD" LocationID="E22C7349-FD77-407A-88A4-BD39A105B986" TransactionTypeID="RE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="1,2,3,4" NumberOfRoomsMin="5" InterfaceLocation="5"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Apartment" DefaultRegionID="446931c9-7efe-440d-b674-24b8659087a7" CurrencyID="USD" TransactionTypeID="SE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="16" SearchBy="ByLocality" InterfaceLocation="5" LocationID="184e17b3-9d27-46fd-8a19-a9f402dfe680" /><Keyid="39fb945c-b048-4942-be86-17f692539ba3"</parameters>
```

it is not a real xml
the key and value are like key="value"

somethimes at the end there is some trash characters

for me the intersting part is from searchname=".."
till the following />

with xml nodes it doesent work neither with regex
has anybody any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What I think is instead of /><Keyid="37ad0ed5-1800-417b-8e17-9ff5084086a2" it should be <Keyid="37ad0ed5-1800-417b-8e17-9ff5084086a2" />. Then the entire string can be wrapped up in a parent element and loaded as xml.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? What results do you expect? What version of SQL Server?

Comment: I expect would be (key SearchName value Flat)  (key SearchFormTemplateId, value Search)....

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can help

```
Declare @String varchar(max) ='
<parameters>SearchName="Flat " SearchFormTemplateId="Search" SearchFormInfo=":ID_.Modules.Business.SearchModule.Label.SearchType.RE.Residential:LDSBL_15 km%15,10 km%10,5 km%5,20 km%20:LSTG_3,2,4:DR_3572ad9b-44cb-4229-a512-3037562d7cc7" SubTypeGroupId="3,2,4" InterfaceLocation="3.5908783699254903"§ CountryId="446931c9-7efe-440d-b674-24b8659087a7" Month="2000" AdMaterialTransactionTypeId="RE"/><azmi/></parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Apartment and.. " CountryID="446931C9-7EFE-440D-B674-24B8659087A7" DefaultRegionID="446931C9-7EFE-440D-B674-24B8659087A7" CurrencyID="USD" LocationID="5A7FCB90-6247-44FD-AB2E-61FEABEA1246,AFAC41AE-0877-45E1-BAA6-1846E9D92332,CCB35927-94CE-4F41-B4BA-695A0396DC5A,B93B2C1F-460A-4726-8B51-FFBEFC15C810,4E701DB8-6B3B-4C0E-91FB-352BEF05FB40,9FA7B3DA-9D36-4742-8526-5143F01E6089,384AF508-D5DC-4ED1-93D2-635180447A8D,49B571CC-FC2E-40F0-A5A7-722D6D1F5926,B0CA4856-427B-4C93-A085-95FA36C082B8,3590075E-9A63-4AF5-BE88-9C8BB70BACB7,E1283086-8C38-4A97-B858-ABE5940F2986,78060DDC-3F00-4AF0-AD17-AC0007FE0622,FE815C24-94D5-4107-989D-B0F5FB5280E8,356F506E-09C1-4E1E-B54E-C54E80E502DF,F028F134-4C13-491B-846C-D85B4D979A5F,7E4013DB-2DE3-401B-9AFF-F41C16B12DB4,5C59BC43-63B7-45D5-8963-F916A71ED889,DA8D9F2D-1C43-443A-86C7-F9661FF06830" TransactionTypeID="RE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="1,2,3,4" MMAX="2100" MoMin="1500" NumberOfRoomsMin="3" InterfaceLocation="1"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Apartment" DefaultRegionID="446931c9-7efe-440d-b674-24b8659087a7" CurrencyID="USD" TransactionTypeID="SE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="4" MMIN="100000" SearchBy="ByLocality" InterfaceLocation="1" LocationID="09194e31-1b5e-482b-9775-41886a1d1167" /><Keyid="6f4037e2-69ba-402d-a8ac-286b04e2bf3b"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Location, 3 rooms" CurrencyID="USD" LocationID="f5812b35-e952-4e3e-a3f1-b0d678616826" TransactionTypeID="RE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="2,3" MMAX="2500" NumberOfRoomsMin="3" SurfaceLivibleMin="80" SearchBy="WithoutGeo" InterfaceLocation="2" /><Keyid="079bb71a-8f01-42fd-a956-0be2239be0ef"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Flat..." DefaultRegionID="446931c9-7efe-440d-b674-24b8659087a7" CurrencyID="USD" TransactionTypeID="RE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="1,2,3" MMAX="4050" MoMin="2700" NumberOfRoomsMin="4.0" SearchBy="ByLocality" InterfaceLocation="1" LocationID="e22c7349-fd77-407a-88a4-bd39a105b986" /><Keyid="44e05bf1-8a26-48b6-b12b-5a652d586d78"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Apartment -" DefaultRegionID="446931c9-7efe-440d-b674-24b8659087a7" CurrencyID="USD" TransactionTypeID="RE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="4" MoMin="500" SearchBy="ByLocality" InterfaceLocation="1" LocationID="e7148138-5be1-46c5-98b1-5ca2edeeb9da" /><Keyid="37ad0ed5-1800-417b-8e17-9ff5084086a2"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Rent dsfsd" CurrencyID="USD" TransactionTypeID="RE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="4" SearchBy="WithoutGeo" /><Keyid="d695f924-6ce6-405b-a561-fa3269f41221"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Apartement ..." DefaultRegionID="446931c9-7efe-440d-b674-24b8659087a7" CurrencyID="USD" AreaID="e90f1e83-ce84-46b6-826a-3775ffd2815d,dc2c2435-b773-424f-a279-4141efd21b78,ce142f26-2b08-419d-86a2-943bea72b279,b5749fe2-9360-48c0-8ffc-f6c9a343f2fa,a3a559c2-4c7e-4b4c-8314-335e9e655472,c3cd7728-3e6a-4787-959f-8e9e824b02d0" TransactionTypeID="RE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="3,2,4" MMAX="1500" LocationIdAgregate="" AreaIdAgregate="e90f1e83-ce84-46b6-826a-3775ffd2815d,dc2c2435-b773-424f-a279-4141efd21b78,ce142f26-2b08-419d-86a2-943bea72b279,b5749fe2-9360-48c0-8ffc-f6c9a343f2fa,a3a559c2-4c7e-4b4c-8314-335e9e655472,c3cd7728-3e6a-4787-959f-8e9e824b02d0" StateIdAgregate="1D6E6621-3179-4D54-A9D8-89E6F438FF3B,8C79C6B5-B61A-45F9-8560-91AE4825AC6A" InterfaceAreaIdAgregate="e90f1e83-ce84-46b6-826a-3775ffd2815d,dc2c2435-b773-424f-a279-4141efd21b78,ce142f26-2b08-419d-86a2-943bea72b279,b5749fe2-9360-48c0-8ffc-f6c9a343f2fa,a3a559c2-4c7e-4b4c-8314-335e9e655472,c3cd7728-3e6a-4787-959f-8e9e824b02d0" SearchBy="ByRegion" /><Keyid="37ad0ed5-1800-417b-8e17-9ff5084086a2"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Apartment a" DefaultRegionID="446931c9-7efe-440d-b674-24b8659087a7" CurrencyID="USD" AreaID="49401e55-95c1-42cb-9242-9468707e7d8a" TransactionTypeID="SE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="16" AreaIdAgregate="49401e55-95c1-42cb-9242-9468707e7d8a" StateIdAgregate="97F9F29F-149E-4E53-A470-96CC8499A64B" SearchBy="ByRegion" /><Keyid="39fb945c-b048-4942-be86-17f692539ba3"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Apartment, Location, 5 rooms" CountryID="446931C9-7EFE-440D-B674-24B8659087A7" DefaultRegionID="446931C9-7EFE-440D-B674-24B8659087A7" CurrencyID="USD" LocationID="E22C7349-FD77-407A-88A4-BD39A105B986" TransactionTypeID="RE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="1,2,3,4" NumberOfRoomsMin="5" InterfaceLocation="5"</parameters>
<parameters>SearchName="Apartment" DefaultRegionID="446931c9-7efe-440d-b674-24b8659087a7" CurrencyID="USD" TransactionTypeID="SE" PropertySubTypeGroupID="16" SearchBy="ByLocality" InterfaceLocation="5" LocationID="184e17b3-9d27-46fd-8a19-a9f402dfe680" /><Keyid="39fb945c-b048-4942-be86-17f692539ba3"</parameters>
'

Declare @Map table (MapSeq int,MapFrom varchar(50),MapTo varchar(50))
Insert Into @Map values 
(1,'<parameters>',' '),
(1,'</parameters>','||'),
(2,'</',' '),
(2,'<',' '),
(2,'>',' '),
(2,'/',' '),
(9,'azmi',''),      -- Caused and Exception First Row:  ...RE"/><azmi/></parameters>
(9,'§','')          -- Caused and Exception First Row:  value outside a quoted attribute value

Select @String   = Replace(@String,MapFrom,MapTo) From @Map
Declare @NewString varchar(max) ='';Select @NewString = @NewString + NewString from (Select NewString='<row id="'+cast(Key_PS as varchar(25))+'" '+Key_Value+' />' from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@String,'||') Where Key_Value <>'') A 

Declare @XML xml = cast(@NewString as XML)
Select ID    = r.value('@id','int')
      ,Item  = Attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
      ,Value = Attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
 From  @XML.nodes('/row') as A(r)
 Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*[local-name(.)!="id"]') as B(Attr)
```

Returns

```
ID  Item                    Value
1   SearchName              Flat 
1   SearchFormTemplateId    Search
1   SearchFormInfo          :ID_.Modules.Business.SearchModule.Label.SearchType.RE.Residential:LDSBL_15 km%15,10 km%10,5 km%5,20 km%20:LSTG_3,2,4:DR_3572ad9b-44cb-4229-a512-3037562d7cc7
1   SubTypeGroupId          3,2,4
1   InterfaceLocation       3.5908783699254903
1   CountryId               446931c9-7efe-440d-b674-24b8659087a7
1   Month                   2000
1   AdMaterialTransactionTypeId     RE
2   SearchName              Apartment and.. 
2   CountryID               446931C9-7EFE-440D-B674-24B8659087A7
2   DefaultRegionID         446931C9-7EFE-440D-B674-24B8659087A7
2   CurrencyID              USD
...
11  SearchName              Apartment
11  DefaultRegionID         446931c9-7efe-440d-b674-24b8659087a7
11  CurrencyID              USD
11  TransactionTypeID       SE
11  PropertySubTypeGroupID  16
11  SearchBy                ByLocality
11  InterfaceLocation       5
11  LocationID              184e17b3-9d27-46fd-8a19-a9f402dfe680
11  Keyid                   39fb945c-b048-4942-be86-17f692539ba3
```

The UDF Parser

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1), Key_Value varchar(max))
As
Begin
   Declare @XML xml;Set @XML = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)
   Insert Into @ReturnTable Select ltrim(rtrim(String.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))) FROM @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)
   Return 
End
```